# Cordova : Android device current date/time

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am working on a project (`Android application` using `Apache Cordova HTML CSS JS`).
I want to get the `device current time and date`.

I checked all the questions but none gives me a solution. Can someone help, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code shows how to get datetime try this

```
var currentdate = new Date(); 
var datetime =  currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + currentdate.getSeconds();
```